# React page alignement broken when adding Gallery component

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have found the solution on the web but nothing works. I have a web page with sections and I am trying to display each section one after the other vertically.

Below is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import './Profile.css';

import UserProfile from '../assets/fake/studentinfo'
import TextContents from '../assets/translations/TextContents';
import Gallery from 'react-grid-gallery';
import DetailReview from '../components/materialdesign/DetailReview';


class Profiles extends React.Component{

    render(){
        const IMAGES =
        [{
                src: "https://c2.staticflickr.com/9/8817/28973449265_07e3aa5d2e_b.jpg",
                thumbnail: "https://c2.staticflickr.com/9/8817/28973449265_07e3aa5d2e_n.jpg",
                thumbnailWidth: 156,
                thumbnailHeight: 156
        },
        {
                src: "https://c2.staticflickr.com/9/8356/28897120681_3b2c0f43e0_b.jpg",
                thumbnail: "https://c2.staticflickr.com/9/8356/28897120681_3b2c0f43e0_n.jpg",
                thumbnailWidth: 156,
                thumbnailHeight: 156
        },
        
        {
                src: "https://c4.staticflickr.com/9/8887/28897124891_98c4fdd82b_b.jpg",
                thumbnail: "https://c4.staticflickr.com/9/8887/28897124891_98c4fdd82b_n.jpg",
                thumbnailWidth: 156,
                thumbnailHeight: 156
        },
        {
            src: "https://c2.staticflickr.com/9/8356/28897120681_3b2c0f43e0_b.jpg",
            thumbnail: "https://c2.staticflickr.com/9/8356/28897120681_3b2c0f43e0_n.jpg",
            thumbnailWidth: 156,
            thumbnailHeight: 156
        }]

        return(
            <div className="profile-container">
                <div className="profile-header" 
                    style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${UserProfile.User1.values.profileHeaderImag})`}}>
                        <img 
                        src={UserProfile.User1.values.profileImg} 
                        alt="profileImg"
                        className="profile-header-image-user"/>                    
                </div>
                <div className="profile-content">
                    <h1> {UserProfile.User1.values.name} </h1>
                    <h3> {UserProfile.User1.values.city}  </h3>
                    <h2> {TextContents.Biography} </h2>
                    <p> {UserProfile.User1.values.bio}  </p>
                    <h2> {TextContents.PhotosVideos} </h2>
                    <div className="profile-gallery">
                        <Gallery images={IMAGES}/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="profile-tabs">
                    <h1> let's put the tabs layout</h1>
                </div>

                <h2>{TextContents.Reviews}</h2>
                    {
                        UserProfile.User1.values.reviews.map((review_item, i) => {
                            return (<DetailReview data={review_item} />);
                        })
                    }
            </div>
        )
    }   
}

export default Profiles;
```

and css

```
.profile-container {
        margin-top: 3rem;
        margin-bottom:5rem;

}

.profile-header {
    position: relative;
    height: 300px;
    width: 70%;
    background-size: 100% 100% no-repeat;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 145px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;

}


.profile-header-image-user {
    position: absolute;
    height: 156px;
    width: 156px;
    border: 1px solid white;
    border-radius: 50%;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 50px;
    transform: translateY(50%);
    box-shadow: inherit;
    margin-left: 2.7%;
}

.profile-content {
    width: 60%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.profile-gallery {
    margin-top:  3%;
}

.profile-tabs {
    width: 60%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

but it looks like this:

[image]

Normally, `let's put the tabs layout`, Reviews,... should be below the image gallery

Any idea why?

Comment: Let me try installing this gallery library and debug in my own project, I'll get back to you soon. I have seen in most of these cases, Library specific CSS takes precedence over our custom CSS and things doesn't work as expected. But without debugging we can't come to any conclusion. Give me a moment. Let me figure it out. Because the trouble seems just after the Gallery Component only.

Comment: Your Code is Debugged and the Issue was coming from the Gallery Library Itself.

Comment: Your problem is solved @Seb. Do rate if it has helped you :) Thank you

Comment: Kindly update the Title of this Question by sth like"  'react-grid-gallery' Issue with positioning Sibling Components." Or some better Question Title, that you feel is related to this problem. This can help many developers out there who may face the similar problem in Future. Thank you

Comment: @ImranRafiqRather thanks a lot. I do have a quick additional question. how do you think I could change the image tile inside the gallery I just want to add Rounded corner and little bit more space between each image

Comment: You are most welcome...  So you want a Rounded Corner and more Space. Since you are using the react-grid-gallery, Did you find other configurations of Gallery Component,... Usually these libraries uses additional props to help us with custom styling. If you have already tried it and still couldn't solve it. Please let me know, I promise  I will sort it out for you :) I am here for about 1hour and 36min. Reach out to me during this time. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]The issue is happening because of the default CSS used by the `Gallery` Component in the `'react-grid-gallery'` library.

Add the below CSS code in your CSS file to solve this issue:

```
#ReactGridGallery{
  display:flex;
}
```

And this will resolve it for you.